# How to combain two inline functions in ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How can I declare below given two ng-class in one:

```
<ion-item class="item-positive item-text-wrap"
          ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(faq)}"
          ng-class="isGroupShown(faq) ? 'item-royal' : 'item-stable'">
```

Comment: @SandeepSukhija see both are different condition, referring your link I tried to do this way but nothing works. `ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(faq), isGroupShown(faq) ? 'item-royal' : 'item-calm'} ">`

Comment: @SandeepSukhija I did this and now working as needed. 
`ng-class="isGroupShown(faq) ? 'item-royal active' : 'item-calm'"`